# How do does that work in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

IF NOT mouseover/-enter/click on div "menu" THEN do stuff ELSE do other stuff?

I dont know the jquery equivalent,
is there one for that?

Thanks!

Comment: it's not jQuery, it's just javascript. Google "javascript if/else statements". w3schools should be helpful.

Comment: oops, thanx :(, im using jquery to play vids with the vimeo api ...  
function playingVid1() {
$('#menu').animate({"bottom": "-56px"}, "slow");
$('#Logo').fadeOut('slow');
}
but the #menu should get animated back when its clicked/moused on even when the video is playing, on mouseout/leave animated to its prior state again (before click/hover menu div, that is...)

Comment: regardless of whether or not you're using jQuery, the syntax will be the same. jQuery is a javascript library, so a lot of the things you do in jQuery are exactly the same as the would be if you weren't using a library.

Comment: @Suri, It would be much better if you put your question in the content instead of title!

Comment: Thank you, i will do that in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the `not` away and exchange `do stuff` with `do other stuff`.